# My HP 745 G5 won’t turn on after water spillage

Tags: laptop, water-damage

I spilled water on my laptop (HP 745 G5) and I switch it off after 30min and next day it won't come on but it has sound and it's not charging I need help what should I do

Comment: Sounds like it's done for, time to get a new one. I'd pull the drive out incase it can be salvaged.

Comment: What do you mean by “it has sound”? How exactly did you spill water on it? Onto the keyboard? Onto the display? How much? Was it really water or juice or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the battery and bios backup battery, even if you have to take it apart. Then put the laptop and batteries in a tupper-ware container or large bag with lots of rice over night. Reassemble and test. If this does not work then do as spikey_richie suggested and salvage the drive and get a new laptop.

Take note of the lenght size and location of the screws with pictures or drawings, so you know where they go when you put it back together.

Comment: Use one baggie for each different size/type of screw to avoid losing them.